# Yii Unit-Testing CDbException

Tags: php, mysql, phpunit, yii

I'm trying to test my Yii-Application with PHPUnit and getting a CDbException. I'm getting the same Exception when I'm using Yii::app()->db.

My PHP-Test-Code:

```
$connection=new CDbConnection('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb','user','pw');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Site";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$rowCount=$command->execute();
echo $rowCount;
```

The Exception:

```
CDbException: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.

/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:388
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:330
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:480
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms/protected/tests/unit/TestTest.php:26
```

When I'm calling index-test.php in my Browser, Yii connects correctly to the test DB, I've defined in the test.php config.

I hope you can help me with this little problem.

Comment: in main application this connection works fine?

Comment: I think there must be problem with path please first sure about it.

Comment: @ Alex: In main and test Application, when I call in Browser index.php (localhost/project/index.php) the development DB is connected and when I call index-test.php (localhost/project/index-test.php) the test DB is connected.
@Anil Bhattarai100: What do you mean with path and witch path do you mean? A Path in bootstrap.php or in phpunit.xml or somewhere else?

Comment: @mrbirne can you let me know what you are using MAMP, XAMPP

Comment: I'm using XAMPP and this is the Problem or not? Becouse the console use an other php.ini then the server? But how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with two solutions for this problem:

First adding the mysql.sock to the test.php config:

```
'db'=>array(
      'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=trackstar_dev;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
      'username'=>'root',
      'password'=>'root',
      'emulatePrepare'=>true
),
```

Second using the xampp php to run phpunit:

```
$ /pathtoxampp/bin/php phpunit /yourtestpath/
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I have also suffered from the similar problem. the following helped for me. Try this once
The solution was to add the line below in php-cli.ini :

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

Comment: I've added this line but I get this exception: 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: please download that file and put that file to the path need location asked by your error

Comment: I've done this but now I'm getting this Error: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/php_pdo_mysql.dll: invalid ELF header in Unknown on line 0

Comment: will you please once restart your apchae

Comment: then please uncomment the extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll and follow this and dig your solution http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29533-chapter-4-dbtest-failed/page__gopid__150351#entry150351

Comment: Thx Anil I never thought that the problem would be the mysql.sock